# Laravel Database Migrations Naming for $table->morphs()?

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

According to the doc for a table name like tags is: `$table->morphs('taggable');`

but what about a name like product_tags?

`$table->morphs('producttagable');`

or

`$table->morphs('product_tagable');`

or

`$table->morphs('productTagable');`

also in modal:

```
  public function tagable()
  {
      return $this->morphTo();
  }
```

what is the correct function name for product_tags?

Comment: Nothing wrong with `producttaggable`.

Answer (score 1):

The helper `$table->morphs(...)` creates a `..._id` and `..._type`, as stated in the docs here https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations#creating-columns :

> Adds taggable_id UNSIGNED BIGINT and taggable_type VARCHAR equivalent columns.

So your parameter `'taggable'` is just the prefix. I usually use the name `'morphable'` which is a more generic way of defining the column names.

You can then use it in your relations like:

```php
public function posts()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Post', 'morphable');
}
```

which will then make the relations on the `morphable_id` and `morphable_type` columns.

Comment: Unless there are 2 polymorphic relationships in a database table, then you will need another definable name.

Comment: true, although i havent encountered that situation yet, because it sounds like a god table (add a `$casts = ['data' => 'array']` for a `data`column to it and you can basically manage your whole database in 1 table :p)

Comment: Isn't that called WordPress :) its rare but I've had it a couple of times, you could just create the polymorphic many to polymorphic many table for any many to many requirements :)